# Replace keys in a dictionary

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
event_types={"as":0,"ah":0,"es":0,"eh":0,"os":0,"oh":0,"cs":0,"ch":0}
```

How can I replace `a` by `append`, `s` by `see`, `h` by `horse`, `e` by `exp` with a space in between.

Output something like:

```
{"append see":0,"append horse":0,"exp horse":0....}
```

Comment: can't you just delete your entries and recreate new ones if your list is so short?

Comment: @JulienBernu It's bigger than that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have another dictionary with your replacements, like this

```
keys = {"a": "append", "h": "horse", "e": "exp", "s": "see"}
```

Now, if your events look like this

```
event_types = {"as": 0, "ah": 0, "es": 0, "eh": 0}
```

Simply reconstruct it with dictionary comprehension, like this

```
>>> {" ".join([keys[char] for char in k]): v for k, v in event_types.items()}   
{'exp see': 0, 'exp horse': 0, 'append see': 0, 'append horse': 0}
```

Here, `" ".join([keys[char] for char in k])`, iterates the characters in the `k`, fetches corresponding words from `keys` dictionary and forms a list. Then, the elements of the list are joined with space character, to get the desired key.

Comment: There is no need for list comprehension: `" ".join([keys[char] for char in k])` -> `" ".join(keys[char] for char in k)`

Comment: @warvariuc join is generally slower with gen exps. That's why I prefer list comprehension always

Comment: This solution assumes that all the old keys are to be replaced, not only two lettered variants. Just noting this as the OP hasn't said anything about it

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you can append or not, but you can do the following one liner:

```
>>> dict={}
>>> dict={"a":"b"}
>>> dict["aha"]=dict.pop("a")
>>> dict
{'aha': 'b'}
```

You can traverse the keys and change them according to your need.

Answer (score 4):

First create a mapping dictionary to map the single letters to words:

```
mm={"a":"append", "s":"see","h":"horse","e":"exp","c":"corn","o":"ocelot"}
```

then transform your input dictionary to a list of key, value tuples, rewrite the key using the mapping dict and create a new list of tuples consisting of new key, original value, finally transform the list of tuples to a dict.

```
dict(map(lambda e: ("%s %s" % (mm[e[0][0]], mm[e[0][1]]), e[1]), event_types.items()))
```

Answer (score 3):

Iterate on keys and values of the original dictionary, transform the key, then store the value in the result dictionary using the transformed key. To transform the key, map over its characters, replace by looking up in a mapping dictionary (`{ "a" : "append", ... }`), then join with spaces.